# AWS eb deploy Changes httpd.conf Virtual Hosts Document Root

Tags: amazon-web-services, httpd.conf, elastic-beanstalk, documentroot

I run an AWS ElasicBeanstalk Apache server. There is a subdomain with a different DocumentRoot (see below). When I use `eb deploy` and then ssh into the machine to manually change the `/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf` file, everything works just fine.

If however I do `eb deploy` **again**, the `DocumentRoot` in the http.conf file changes from `"/var/www/html/sub/"` to `"/var/www/html/"`, the rest of the file remains unchanged.

I suppose eb deploy must somehow rewrite the httpd.conf file, but I am puzzled as to why only the document root changes.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sub/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can get my subdomains working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk overrides manual configurations upon deployments. [Ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) helps to load custom changes to eb environments.